# Continually Running Background Service on latest version android 11 and 12

Tags: android, service, background, react-navigation

I googled a lot and search also on  a over stack  flow i did not get any proper solution for Continously location update when mobile on background mode.

I have also use  workmanager Periodic
request but its Minimum interval is 15 minute then how get the location get sceconds.

I am working on react native tracking project  i have create a native module  for run services. but my service killed after sometime in background mode.  but in working on forground service .

If any one use  background  location updates on mobile  version 11 and 12 .Let me know and also share github link  or  code.

Thank you

Comment: You need to use a foreground service

Answer (score 1):

You can only take continuous background location using Foreground service. Background service are not meant for this. Refer this link on how to create and use a foreground service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services

Comment: continuous background location  working on below devices  any specific  code for android 12  only

Comment: If you are facing problem with android 12 only then make sure you have the background location permission. From android 12, user needs to explicitly give background location permission from settings, unlike previous versions where a popup used to come for background location permission: https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#:~:text=On%20Android%2012%20and%20higher,to%20Android%2012%20or%20higher.

Comment: Thanks mohit48  , i am already use  this permission   for android 12   Below is my small code.  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
      { } );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }   before started tracking for location update i have granted this permission.  but i dont know  why app killed after some  time on android 12.

Comment: Background service will not work for your purpose anyway, you will have to use Foreground service. This is how I do in any app where it is required.

Answer (score 1):

Check this React-native library no need to create custom native modules , check : [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)

Why should you use this library

> This library is created in an attempt to fix the location timeout issue on android with the react-native's current implementation of Geolocation API. This library tries to solve the issue by using Google Play Service's new FusedLocationProviderClient API, which Google strongly recommends over android's default framework location API. It automatically decides which provider to use based on your request configuration and also prompts you to change the location mode if it doesn't satisfy your current request configuration.

Usage:

```
...
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
...

componentDidMount() {
  if (hasLocationPermission) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          console.log(position);
        },
        (error) => {
          // See error code charts below.
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    );
  }
}
```

***Edit***:

you could use [watchPosition](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service#watchpositionsuccesscallback-errorcallback-options)

```
Geolocation.watchPosition(
(position) => {
  console.log(position);
},
(error) => {
  // See error code charts below.
  console.log(error.code, error.message);
},
{ enableHighAccuracy: true, interval: 1000 }
```

);

above code has `interval` param of the `watchPosition` is set to 1 sec so it will get update active location updates (android only)
remember to stop all these observers.

Comment: I have also use react-native-geolocation-service  npm  , how get the updates  location  from every seconds  for tracking app  on android 12 version . Please let me know Thanks

Comment: try the watchPosition code. It should give you location update after 1 sec

Comment: Thank you for respond  . yes i know but location update  not get when our app is in background mode or our phone is locked i am working on android 12 .